# Redirect computer network name to other computer

Tags: windows-xp, networking

A computer on my network has changed name and every time my applications try to reference the computer it halts while searching for it.

Is it possible to do a "redirect" as you do with ip-adresses in the hosts-file in win xp.

127.0.0.1    localhost

But instead:

computer_newname    computer_oldname

This problem is in Windows XP

Comment: what applications? why don't they recognise new computer name?

Comment: mainly 3dsmax, but we have tons of projects done during the last 5 years. Problem is not that the new computername is not recoqnised, but that the old computername is used in the files and hence it takes forever while it is searching for the old, before I can change it to the new one.